How to adapt database-rider to SQLite BLOB data?
I use database-rider for database testing. If I understood right, the binary data in a file-based dataset should be encoded as Base64-string, so we get something like this for xml-dataset:
<dataset>
  <DOC ID="1" CONTENT="REJSaWRlciE="/>
</dataset>

This is works for PostgreSQL from my expireence (and evidently for hsqldb as it is used in database-rider tests), and not works for SQLite. In PostgreSQL binary-data column has a type bytea, so Base64-encoded data somehow converted to byte array while inseting in the table and vice versa from byte array to Base64-text while reading to compare with expected dataset (I think so because I does not do manula data encoding/decoding). But with SQLite if I insert binary data to the table like this
double[] data = entity.getData();
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(data.length * 8);
for (double d : xy) {
  bb.putDouble(d);
}
byte[] bytes = bb.array();
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO sdata(data) VALUES (?)");
statement.setBytes(1, bytes);
Statement.executeUpdate();

then expected data set fails because the data reads by database-rider from SQLite as byte-array but the expected dataset it is encoded as Base64-text, and I got the test failure:
org.dbunit.assertion.DbComparisonFailure[value (table=sdata, row=0, col=data)expected:<QGKubl4SN5lAs7hYfACBhUBjBejffpn+QL...> but was:<@b�n^7�@��X|

So, is it a bug of database-rider or there is some way to converting data between dataset and database (from dataset to SQLite - from Base64-string to byte[]; and vice versa, from SQLite to dataset - from byte[] to Base64-string)? It is seems what for other database it is comes like this.
